# Login/startup sound file help

Tags: 12.04, sound, startup-applications

I am newer to Ubuntu and I am trying to slowly learn.  I have been trying to activate and change my login sound but currently I still hear nothing.  I did hear the login sound at a point and I think I messed it up when I changed  the file.

This is what I have done.  I added a startup application with this command I pasted in, `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login sound"`.  I then typed in `gksu nautilus` and went to `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo` and I changed two files,  `desktop-login.ogg` and `system-startup.ogg`, at least that is what I renamed them.

I renamed the old `desktop-login.ogg` to `system-startup.ogg`, which I thought was that files original name in the same folder just to move it out of the way and keep the sound.  I brought in a new .ogg file and renamed it `desktop-login.ogg` in hopes that the new file would take hold and play in the old files place upon startup/login.  I currently get no sounds. Can anyone find my error? My first thoughts are that the name I made, `system-startup.ogg`, was not the original name.

Comment: i think its the wrong way to change the physical files, take a look at http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/05/how-to-turn-off-or-change-login-sound.html - this may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Terminal and enter this command:

   `gedit ~/.config/autostart/loginsound.desktop`
2. Copy and paste the text below into this new blank file:

   `[Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login"
   Name=Login Sound
   Comment=Play login sound on startup
   Icon=multimedia-volume-control
   Hidden=false
   NoDisplay=true
   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`
3. Exit Gedit saving the modified file.
4. Make sure that you have a file named `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg` and it does play your preferred login sound - you can try the command `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login"` and if you don't hear anything there might be something wrong with that file:

   1. Does it really contain any sound?
   2. Does it have read permissions for all? (You can check this via `gksu nautilus` command or the Properties context menu item.)

Comment: Im not sure if I still needed the code you gave me but after that didn't work I checked the file and indeed it didn't allow any read privileges.

Comment: You can of course achieve this in various ways, but I think this is a good method for enabling login sound in Ubuntu as it is also displayed in **Startup Applications** (GUI) applet.